# Using the Conditional operator in asp.net web forms markup

Tags: asp.net

I have a repeater, that is bound is the level is equal to one, this works great, however if the level is equal to something else, I print out a blank line. How do I get it to not print out anything if Level != 1?

```
<%# ((programsRepeat)Container.DataItem).Level == 1 ? ((programsRepeat)Container.DataItem).ProgramName : "" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

1. Modify your query (filter `WHERE level = 1`)
2. Use code-behind (datatable, etc.) to modify your dataset prior to binding it to the repeater
3. Use the databinding event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.databinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

...